# Connecting Microsoft Azure Sql Database in iOS apllication(help)

Tags: ios, sql, azure, connect

Hello I am a total newbie in `xcode(iOS)` environment, I wrote a program that connects to my `Microsoft Azure sql database` and keep the datas update(in `vb.net`). Now i have 7 tables in mydatabase and I can't connect them. I did tried the quick start application it connects

https://myapplicationname.azure-mobile.net/tables/tablename

but my tables is under my `sql database` not in /tables/ . I googled it and i couldn't find the path of my tables. Well I have connection strings which `Microsoft Azure` provides but I even don't know where to put the connection string. What can I do to connect my tables and read the data.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at Azure Mobile Services?  You can easily create a facade for your database accessible by mobile apps.  Make sure you look at the iOS API.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Azure and the table storage areas are not the same thing... Sounds like you've added the tables to SQL Azure but are trying to connect to table storage to view them.